# NumPY 1.17.0rc1 is available to Python 2.7

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pip

See [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13911) for more details. It looks like there's a bug with pip, or wheel, or something, but my issue is that I just want a work-around while they fix the real problem.

Is there a way around the problem? My work is straggling because I can't install tools that I need to work because pip keeps trying to setup numpy 1.17 on Python 2.7 when I ask it to install SciPy 1.2.2. I tried following the discussion on the GitHub page, but I don't really see a resolution. I just want SciPy 1.2.2 to install without trying to install numpy 1.17. Notable:

numpy 1.16.2 is the last version of numpy for Python2.7, and I have it installed

scipy 1.2.2 should be the last version of scipy for Python2.7, so it shouldn't be trying to install numpy 1.17 when I try to install it

running pip with --no-dependencies doesn't make a difference

Any advice would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
CentOS 6.5 / Rocks 6.1.1
Python 2.7.16
pip 19.1.1
setuptools 41.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me as designed:

```
$ mktmpenv -p python2.7

$ pip --version
pip 19.1.1 from /home/phd/.virtualenvs/tmp-f57314fa7b85dd31/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

$ pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/bd/f0789728ce4a399a5e7bb4af5e6851d239d5cf423bf8888280ec3cd8f1f2/scipy-1.2.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_i686.whl (21.4MB)
     |################################| 21.4MB 12.1MB/s 
Collecting numpy>=1.8.2 (from scipy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/35/51/7eae9042f5904463cb27fea567afc15e90956bd4b7cba98ec1969e58f74a/numpy-1.16.4-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_i686.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy, scipy
Successfully installed numpy-1.16.4 scipy-1.2.2
```

What is your OS? Exact Python 2.7 version? pip version? setuptools?

Comment: I've edited my original comment with this information.

Comment: Is pip for this Python? `pip --version`? Try `python2.7 -m pip` instead of `pip`.